# why little diamonds with question marks comes when i bind some HTML in text area?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

When i try to bind some HTMl code inside text area, all &nbsp shows as little diamonds with question mark.
i'm using smarty template engine.

php code

```
  $mailContent=$emailbody['emailHtml'];
```

smarty code

```
 {form->textarea name="emailContent" cols="110" rows="20" value={$emailbody} class="textarea05" style="witdh:auto;height:auto" tabindex="1" readonly="readonly"}
```

Comment: Trying to display non utf8 text as utf8

Comment: � == Unicode replacement character == Unicode encoding problem. Hard to tell you any fix without more information.

Comment: Short solution: don't copy and paste code out of MS-Word or some websites as the character encoding won't match your browser. Alternately, ensure that your character encoding in the HTML document matches what you are copying from.

Answer (score 1):

Try using escape.

```
 {form->textarea name="emailContent" cols="110" rows="20" value={$emailbody|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} class="textarea05" style="witdh:auto;height:auto" tabindex="1" readonly="readonly"}
```

I used UTF-8 in this example, you'll need to match this to your requirements.

More info here - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape

Comment: i tried damon, but its not working. it's removed html tags too.